# How to center text inside TextView own container?

Tags: android, text, textview, android-gravity

I need to create this :

[image]

As you can see the lines not exactly centered with the text .

The problem ever bigger with Lower case text .

the text is to low , not centered in is own view

this is my code  - The container is Linear Layout with

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal
```

```
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/gray_separator" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="How ?"
    android:textColor="@color/gray_login_or"
    android:textSize="26sp" />

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/gray_separator" />
```

i have tried with Relative Layout but this is not the problem , the problem and the solution in the TextView .

**The best easy way to understand the problem is the different between lower and upper case...in upper case i have no problem .**

Comment: try android:gravity="center" rather than "center_vertical"

Comment: No .I have tried . I don't believe this a gravity issue . Maybe i"m wrong . it is something like AjustViewBounds that is missing

Comment: put all 3 views in a linear layout, then make your textview match parent in height and then use gravity for text alignment

Comment: You pasted three views, what is their parent? This question lacks of information.

Answer (score 1):

I have used :

```
 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

instead of :

```
  android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

And it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/gray_separator"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:text="How ?"
    android:textColor="@color/gray_login_or"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/gray_separator"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I have done for the similar requirement, which works pretty well.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dashline"
            android:layerType="software"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OR"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dashline"
            android:layerType="software"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I am using ImageView as per my need, you can replace them with View which you want.

This is my `dashline.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">

    <stroke
        android:color="#ffffff"
        android:dashWidth="8px"
        android:dashGap="0px"
        android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

Here's the snapshot of the screen portion.

[image]

So `android:layout_gravity="center"` should work.

Comment: if you will change the OR to lowercase you will see the problem , great example

Answer (score 1):

use `android:gravity="center"` in your text view.

Answer (score 1):

I guess parent is a horizontal linear layout. So this should be used:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

instead of

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

but if parent's height is wrap_content, result should be same.

BTW, alphabet fonts are not horizontally in the middle of the space. It is a little lower than center line, which is more comfortable for human eyes. refer to:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Typography_Line_Terms.svg

Answer (score 1):

```
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/black"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/Imagetxt"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Image Cart"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/orange"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/black"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

            </LinearLayout>


                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```